# Place list item at specific position in CheckBox List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two checkboxlist

checkboxlist1 has 5 items and checkboxlist2 has 3 items

During a button event click, i need to move the selected items from checkboxlist1 to checkboxlist2

but i need to make sure the items selected from checkboxlist1 needs to be placed above or below an item checked in checkboxlist2

how to add items at a specific position in checkboxlist2 and move the remaining items down

Below code will actually put the item at the end

```
checkboxlist2.Items.Add(listitemselectedfromcheckboxlist1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
checkboxlist2.Items.Insert(index , listitemselectedfromcheckboxlist1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manipulating `Items` by using `Insert` method overload  ?
I mean

```
checkboxlist2.Items.Insert(index:3,item);
```

Comment: may i know how to get an index of selected list item in checkboxlist2 ?

Comment: index of last selected item should be available in `checkboxlist2.SelectedIndex`

Answer (score 0):

How about using this for multiple selections,

```
checkboxlist1.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    checkboxlist2.Items.Insert(x, checkboxlist1.Items[x]);
});
```

Hope this helps...